# Should we make [average] tag synonym to [mean]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I think [average](/questions/tagged/average) should be synonym to [mean](/questions/tagged/mean).
I do not have enough rep/privileges for making this change (or even propse it).

Can someone please take care of this?

#### Update:

Following the answer I got it seems like it is best **not** to merge these two tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the tag wiki of [average](/questions/tagged/average):

> Many different descriptive statistics can be chosen as a measure of the central tendency of the data items. These include the arithmetic **mean**, the **median**, and the **mode**. Other statistics, such as the standard deviation and the range, are called measures of spread and describe how spread out the data is.

(emphasis mine)

Therefore, the mean is actually a specific subset of the average. These tags should not be merged.

I have [edited the tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2352289) (as suggested by JohnB) to reduce confusion about this in the future.

Comment: Perhaps the excerpt should reflect that the average can include mean, median, and mode? I had not known this, but Wikipedia confirms it as an alternative definition

Comment: @JohnB You're probably right, I'll propose that edit now.

Comment: @JohnB I did not know it either - very confusing...